# How can I deduce if my printer can quickly print at higher resolutions as advertised?

Tags: laser-printer, hp-laserjet

I don't understand [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1453651)...too much tech lingo! If I understand correctly, Damon means that a printer can fail to have enough RAM to print at higher resolutions?

How can I deduce if [this printer](https://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-laserjet-pro-mfp-m426fdw) can quickly print at HP ProRes 1200? See my screen shot below...I think its RAM is 256 MB. How can I deduce if this is enough RAM?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw4d6.jpg)

I already tried FastRes 1200, but it fails to print subscripts and superscripts in my math PDF clearly. I didn't try 600 dpi because Damon wrote that FastRes 1200 prints better quality from 600 dpi.

Comment: If the image (file) you are trying to print is over 256mb in size then the printer will reduce resolution.

Answer (score 0):

It may print certain documents more quickly than a printer with less memory, but we cannot say that it will print them "fast" because there is no standard to determine what "fast" is, and the speed of printing will depend on an exceptional number of factors, very few of which are included in the question.

As the question you've linked notes, pages sent to the print queue become very large very quickly. 256MB is a relatively large amount of memory for a consumer printer, but it is still more or less trivial to generate a document that uses more than that amount of memory. Adjusting your printing settings could allow the document to print without error, but due to increased and delayed communication between the printer and the computer, the job will take longer.